# Find all descendants with recursive CTE

Tags: postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a postgres database like this with table **ids**:

```
  id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  value TEXT,
  parent_id INT REFERENCES ids DEFAULT NULL
```

I want to find amount of descendants for all rows in this table. So for all leaves in the tree subtree size will be 1.

I want to do this with recursive CTE and wrote this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
SELECT id, parent_id
from keyword
where id=1

UNION 

SELECT k.id, k.parent_id
FROM keyword k
join r on k.parent_id = r.id)

select count(*) from r;
```

I only can count descendants for certain id, not for all. I tried to write group by id inside CTE, but it doesn't work (most of the times it gives subtree size equals to 1 for all vertex).

Based on this table,

```
 id | parent_id | value  
 ----+-----------+--------
  1 |           | SELECT
  2 |         1 | FROM
  3 |         1 | WHERE
  4 |         1 | ORDER
  5 |         4 | BY
  6 |         1 | GROUP
  7 |         6 | BY
  8 |         6 | HAVING
 11 |           | UPDATE
 12 |        11 | SET
 13 |        11 | WHERE
```

I want to get that:

```
 id | subtree_size
-------+----------
 1 | 11
 2 | 1
 6 | 3...
```

And for all id that are in the tree.

Comment: All the trees: start by all the roots: `where id=1` -->> `where parent_id IS NULL` And you can retain the root in the result and group on that in the outer query.

Comment: Correction: id=1 has  a subtree_size of 8. ( {11,12,13} are in a separate tree )

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE keyword
        ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
        , parent_id INT REFERENCES keyword(id) DEFAULT NULL
        , value TEXT
        );
INSERT INTO keyword(id,parent_id, value) VALUES
 ( 1, NULL, 'SELECT')
,( 2, 1, 'FROM')
,( 3, 1, 'WHERE')
,( 4, 1, 'ORDER')
,( 5, 4, 'BY')
,( 6, 1, 'GROUP')
,( 7, 6, 'BY')
,( 8, 6, 'HAVING')
,( 11, NULL, 'UPDATE')
,( 12, 11, 'SET')
,( 13, 11, 'WHERE')
        ;


WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
        SELECT id AS root -- <<== 'Anchor' the root
        , id, parent_id
        from keyword
        -- where id=1
        -- where parent_id IS NULL
        WHERE id IN (1,2,6) -- <<== UPDATE
UNION
        SELECT r.root   -- <<== This is the trick: maintain the parent's root
        , k.id, k.parent_id
        FROM keyword k
        join r on k.parent_id = r.id
        )
select distinct k.value, r.root, count(*) AS cnt
from r
JOIN keyword k ON k.id = r.root
GROUP BY r.root, k.value
        ;
```

Comment: It actually counts amount of descendants in the entire tree for root vertex, because r.root will be always the id of root vertex. I need to go through all nodes and count descendants as each of them was a root.

Comment: If there is only one root, there obviously will be only one group and one aggregate. (your question was not very clear in this respect)